# Excel CORREL Function With Unequal Length

Tags: excel, statistics, vba

I have a list of data from A3 to AA3, containing a time series of 25 years and associated data points. It is formatted as below:

[image]

I want to see if the data is autocorrelated. So I want to take the correlation of data points 1 to 25 and data 1 to 24, then 1 to 25 / 1 to 23, 1 to 25 / 1 to 22, and so on to see the correlation for different lags.

Since these arrays aren't going to be equal length for the CORREL function, I'll need to include empty cells. However, since the data is in increasing order, there won't be empty cells to the left.

The data extends for several hundred thousand rows and takes output from another program so it wouldn't be practical to re-organize the data. I am doing the formulas in another sheet that references this sheet with the data.

Given the above constraints, what would be the best way to make the CORREL function work?